# How to return a list defined in function A for use in function B in python?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm new to coding and taking a python course. This is our third program, and the professor has started wanting us to avoid the use of global variables. Originally my function started by defining the main function and the list speedList-

```
speedList=[]
def main(): # Creates list of lists with offender's [name, speed, posted limit]
    file=open('speeds.txt', 'r')
    for line in file:
        stripped=line.strip()
        lineList=stripped.split()
        speedList.append(lineList)
    file.close()
```

In my next function, calcTicket(), I want to reuse speedList in a for loop:

```
for list in speedList:
    speedOver=(int(list[1])-int(list[2]))
    if speedOver<5:
        a+=1
        fine=65
    elif 5<=speedOver<10:
        b+=1
        fine=85
    elif 10<=speedOver<15:
        c+=1
        fine=120
    elif 15<=speedOver<25:
        d+=1
        fine=150
    else:
        e+=1
        fine=200
```

To avoid using global variables, I rewrote a bit and attempted to define speedList at the start of main() and return it at the end of main() for use in calcTicket() instead of defining speedList globally. However, doing this gives me

```
NameError: name 'speedList' is not defined.
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Edit: Rewritten code-

```
def main(): # Creates list of lists with offender's [name, speed, posted limit]
    speedList=[]
    file=open('speeds.txt', 'r')
    for line in file:
        stripped=line.strip()
        lineList=stripped.split()
        speedList.append(lineList)
    file.close()
    return speedList

def calcTicket(): # Determines MPH over posted limit, appropriate fine, offenses per range. Prints table.
    a=b=c=d=e=0
    print("Name" + "MPH Over".rjust(22) + "Fine".rjust(10))
    print("-"*37)
    for list in speedList:
        speedOver=(int(list[1])-int(list[2]))
        if speedOver<5:
            a+=1
            fine=65
        elif 5<=speedOver<10:
            b+=1
            fine=85
        elif 10<=speedOver<15:
            c+=1
            fine=120
        elif 15<=speedOver<25:
            d+=1
            fine=150
        else:
            e+=1
            fine=200
        print(list[0]+str(speedOver).rjust(20-len(list[0]))+str(fine).rjust(15))
    print("-"*37)
    print("Tickets less than 5 MPH over: "+str(a))
    print("Tickets between 5 and 10 MPH over: "+str(b))
    print("Tickets between 10 and 15 MPH over: "+str(c))
    print("Tickets between 15 and 25 MPH over: "+str(d))
    print("Tickets greater than 25 MPH over: "+str(e))

main()
calcTicket()
```

Comment: You can't just use variables defined in other methods, read about `variable scope`

Comment: You could return it from the function where it is defined and pass it to where you're using it.

Comment: Can you show the code that is producing the `NameError` you quote? Because your description of what you tried sounds right, so you might just have a detail wrong in there.

Comment: @joanis - I edited the post with the full rewritten code giving me the error.

Answer (score 2):

Change `calcTicket` to take an argument;

```
calclTicket(speedList):
    ...
```

Then

```
something = main()
calcTicket(something)
```

Comment: What's the reasoning for assigning main() to a variable before using it as an argument in calcTicket()? Your suggestion fixed the problem, but it also works if I just run calcTicket(main())

Comment: @Polyicio - I imagine the reason is that I like to do it that way and there is no reason not to. Why do you prefer `calcTicket(main())`?

Comment: @Polyicio - I guess over time I got used to using intermediate variables because it aided debugging and testing so it became a habit rather than a preference. *Explicit is better than implicit. Flat is better than nested. Readability counts.* ||| `import this`